# Generate general schema of a huge unknown database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am required to make a general schema of a huge database that I have never used.
The problem is that I do not know how/where could I start doing this because, not considering the size, I have no idea of what is each table for. I can guess some but there are the mayority of them in which generic name fields do not say anything to me.

Do you have some advice?what could I do?
There is no documentation about the database and the creators are not able to help me because they are in another company now.

Thank you very much in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't going to be easy.

Start by gathering any documentation, notes, etc. that exist. Also, it'll greatly help to have a thorough understanding of the type of data being stored, and of the application. Keep ample notes of your discoveries, and build the documentation that *should* have been built before.

If your database contains declared foreign keys, you can start there, and at least get down the relationships between the tables. Keeping in mind that this may be incomplete. As @John Watson points out, if the relationships are declared, there are tools to do this for you.

Check for stored functions and procedures, including triggers. Though these are somewhat uncommon in MySQL databases. Triggers especially will often yield clues ("every update to table X inserts a new row to table Y" -> "table Y is probably a log or audit table").

Some of the tables are hopefully obvious, and if you know what is related to them, you may be able to start figuring out those related tables.

Hopefully you have access to application code, which you can grep and read to find clues. Access to a test environment which you can destroy repeatedly will be useful too ("what happens if I change this in the app, where does the database change?"; "what happens if I scramble these values?"; etc.). You can dump tables and use `diff` on them, provided you dump them ordered by primary or unique key.

Doing queries like `SELECT DISTINCT foo FROM table` can help you see what different things can be in a column.

If its possible to start from a mostly-empty database (e.g., minimal to get the app to run), you can observe what changes as you add data to the app. Much quicker to dump the database when its small. Same for diffing it, same for reading through the output. Some things are easier to understand in a tiny database, but some things are more difficult. When you have a huge dataset and a column is always 3, you can be much more confident it always is.

You can watch SQL traffic from the application(s) to get an idea of what tables and columns they access for each function, and how they join them. Watching SQL traffic can be done in application-specific ways (e.g., DBI trace) or server-specific ways (turn on the general query log) or with a packet tracer like Wireshark or tcpdump. Which is appropriate is going to depend on the environment you're working in. E.g., if you have to do this on a production system, you probably want Wireshark. If you are doing this in dev/test, the disadvantage of the MySQL query log is that all the apps may very well be mixed together, and if multiple people are hitting the apps it'll get confusing. The app-specific log probably won't suffer from this, but of course the app may not have that.

Keep in mind the various ways data can be stored. For example, all three of these could mean May 1, 1980:

1. 1980-05-01 — As a DATE, TIMESTAMP, or text.
2. 2444330.5 — Julian day (with time, specifies at midnight)
3. 44360 — Modified Julian day
4. 326001600 — UNIX timestamp (with time, specifies midnight) assuming local time is US Eastern Time (seconds since Jan 1 1970 UTC)

There may be things in the database which are denormalized, and some of them may be denormalized incorrectly. E.g., you may be wondering "why does this user have a first name Bob in one table, and a first name Joe in another?" and the answer is "data corruption".

There may be columns that aren't used. There may be entire tables that aren't used. Despite this, they may still have data from older versions of the app (or other, no-longer-in-use apps), queries run from the MySQL console, etc.

There may be things which aren't visible in the application anywhere, but are used. Their purpose may be completely non-obvious without knowledge of the algorithms implemented in the app(s). For example, a search function in an app may store all kinds of precomputed information about the documents to search and their connections. Worse, these tables may only be updated by batch jobs, so changing a document won't touch them (making you mistakenly believe they have nothing to do with documents). Then, you come in the next morning, and the table is mysteriously very different. Though, in the search case, a query log when running search will tell you.

Comment: For me, the first step would be reverse engineering a database diagram from the actual database. There are [tools available](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sql+reverse+engineer#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&source=hp&q=database+diagram+reverse+engineering&pbx=1&oq=database+diagram+reverse+engineering&aq=f&aqi=g-v1&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=20810l25265l0l25377l36l14l0l18l18l2l341l2920l0.6.6.2l24l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=b571422ac7922aeb&biw=1280&bih=939) that will do that for you. That will hopefully give you a nice visual map.

Comment: Thank you very much for everything! I am a little bit concerned by the situation but I will try to follow all your advices. I like the idea of the reverse engineering to get the diagram. Maybe starting there I can start figuring out the relationships between tables and get the ideas of what is going on. Again, thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: @Fran: I think I've managed to write down all my suggestions now—you may want to reread or at least check the [edit log](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7905132/revisions).

Comment: @derobert Thank you very much for all your help, I really appreciate it :) I will check everything again carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the free [mySQL workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) (it's specific to mySQL).
I have reverse engineered databases this way and also ended up with great Entity Relationship Diagrams!
I've worked with SQL for 20 years and this product really is great (it's free, from the mysql folks themselves).
It can have occasional problems, crashes, etc. at least it did on Ubuntu10 but they've been relatively rare and far out-weighed by the benefits!  It's also actively developed so bugs are actually fixed on an on-going basis.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I will try this tool then

Comment: I agree, I've used this tool to great effect also... The really nice thing is it uses any foreign-key relationships that are defined in order to build the ERD joins between tables! :)

Comment: Please see how it goes and if it helps you please feel free to up-check my answer if it works ;)

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I was trying MySQL worbench, as you said, but the problem is that the database is MyISAM, so it does not include support for foreign keys in the ERR schema. I will investigate if there is some other tool or a plugin for MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that nobody bothered to declare foreign keys in the table definition, and the database belongs to an application which is in use, after grabbing the current schema, the next step for me would be to enable logging of all queries (hoping that the data does NOT use a trivial ORM like [x]hibernate) to identify joins and data semantics.

[This perl script](http://www.retards.org/projects/mysql/) may be helpful.

Comment: I will check this script after getting the schema then. Thank you very much!